# SetTiemout in SetInterval?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a strange problem, well I'm trying to make a loop using setInterval but i want to have a SetTimeout inside as well.

Comment: what's the problem? you've created two functions but never call them - not sure why each time the interval is triggered you want to clear it, then re-create it ... looks like you're trying to make setInterval work like setTimeout

Comment: Even tho I run it, it works only for the first time. Just forgot to add init(); in this example.

Comment: Why use `setInterval` if you are going to `clearInterval` inside it?

Comment: What the heck are you trying to acheive with this?

Comment: Well, am trying to do a function where something has to be delayed with SetTimeout and after SetTimeout is done, continue the setInterval and clear it after the whole function is done.

Comment: your code starts an interval every second which stops and restarts itself ... after 8 seconds, each of the timeouts starts to trigger ... so you have init/test ... a second later you have interval/init/test running every second ... after 8 seconds you'll get timeout/interval/init/test running every second

Comment: @JaromandaX How should I do it correctly?

Comment: no idea as I don't really understand the point of your code, and your description in the comment hasn't helped much

Comment: what is the problem? you are facing here and where did you call this `init()` function at initially.

Comment: @JaromandaX Well, let's say I want to create a function that prints a simple console.log and after 8 seconds, it will print another one and after it is done, clear the interval.

Comment: When you do setTimeout(init, 1000); it calls init and goes directly back to test() so why go back to init when you can just do setTimeout(test, 1000)

Comment: why would you need an interval that runs every 1 second to do so ... seems you need a single setTimeout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems, from the comments, what you need is just

```
var init = function() {
    setTimeout(function(){ 
        console.log("Hi");
        init(); // only call init here to start again if need be
    }, 8000);
}
init();
```

> based on the comment below, I'm assuming the interval needs to be "paused" sometimes because in your comment you say `at some point, I have to delay one action` - which implies that this delay isn't always necessary. Given that, you could write it as follows

```
var test = function() {
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
        if (someCondition) {
           clearInterval(interval); // stop the interval
            setTimeout(function(){ 
                console.log("Hi");
                test(); // restart the interval
            }, 8000);

        } else {
            // this is done every second, except when "someCondition" is true
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

or even

```
var running = true;
var test = function() {
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
        if (someCondition) {
           running = false; // stop the interval
            setTimeout(function(){ 
                console.log("Hi");
                running = true; // restart the interval
            }, 8000);

        } else if (running) {
            // this is done every second, only when "running" is true
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: That is what I was exactly trying to archive, but the problem is I want to have that kind of setTimeout inside an Interval, let's say I have code running in the interval and at some point, i have to delay one action with setTimeout, how do I archive that?

Comment: I've updated my question, maybe it's much cleaner now.

Comment: in your question `if (hero.x == heros.x && hero.y == heros.y)` is analogous to my `if (someCondition) {` - of course, the code in the question now looks totally different to my answer!!

Comment: erm `for (var x in heros) {
            var heros = heros[x];` that's not real code because it really wont do anything you expect

Comment: I know, just wrote it as an example. :)

Comment: it's really difficult to give a meaningful answer, as your two "minimal" examples of code have been vastly different, and trying to read between the errors, even the overall functionality of the two pieces of code you've thus far presented seems to be different ... i.e. NOW, the interval is stopped once the timeout expires, and never restarted